# Append data to pandas DF within loop using iterrows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, append

[SOLVED]

this worked for:

```
for lab, row in consig_df.iterrows():
     consig_df.loc[lab,"start_loan"] = d - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=row["number_of_quotas_paid"])
```

[SOLVED]

I have the following df:

[edit]

```
       total_value           quotas_value    term            number_of_quotas_paid
0         3500.00            544.21           24                     24   
1        11226.17            648.55           60                     24   
2        11547.00            578.06           96                     18   
3         1500.00            418.99            4                      0   
4         5500.00           2928.49            2                      0   
5         7758.00            393.00           60                     12   
6         1000.00            532.84            2                      2   
7         2250.00            623.95            4                      0   
8          600.00            217.97            3                      3   
9          600.00            165.85            4                      2
```

I want to run a loop, create a new row and append the data. I'm trying to calculate what month the loan started based on the number of quotas already paid.

I'm stuck after the loop.

```
import datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta

d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-08-01", "%Y-%m-%d")

for lab, row in consig_df.iterrows():

    comeco = d - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=row["number_of_quotas_paid"])
```

How do I go from here, create a new row and append the data generated through the loop?

thanks

Comment: You probably don't want to use iterrows here... It also looks like you have a *column* and not a row... could you provide an example of your DF? You can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples for some hints on forming a solveable pandas question.

Comment: You're right. I meant column. What do you suggest instead of iterrows?

Comment: Nothing at the moment as no one has an idea of what your actual data looks like and thus what options may be available - but it's almost certainly not `iterrows`... :)

Comment: just added an example. thanks for the patience .

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to add the details :)

Comment: Something like: `pd.to_datetime('2018-08-01') - pd.to_timedelta(df.number_of_quotas_paid, unit='M')` probably gets you close, but you probably want to specify how you want to anchor the results?

Comment: When I run the code giving a specific value it works fine.
 
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-08-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
comeco = d - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=2)

my problem is with the loop + append.

Comment: Right... but you shouldn't really need an explicit loop... is the above close to what you're after?

Comment: got it! thanks for your attention!!